# Laravel - Export project in other folder for deployment

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, composer-php

Is there a way to clean unused dependencies and **composer dev requires** to reduce a Laravel project, because it's so heavy (43,3 Mb) and it's a small project. Btw, I'm using some dev helpers like Debugbar and IDEHelpers which are not used for deployment...

Is there a way to make a deployment version of my project in other folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to deploy your app is **without the vendor directory**. I'm going to assume that you're using git for your project. First, put the following in your `.gitignore`.

```
/vendor/
```

Now remove the vendor directory from your repository

```
git rm -r --cached vendor
git commit -m 'Removed vendor directory'
```

Now you have a two step deployment:

1. Update the app using `git pull` or however you usually deploy.
2. Run `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`. This will generate your vendor directory omitting any development only dependencies.

In order to take advantage of the `--no-dev` flag, you need to put your development dependencies in the `require-dev` section in your `composer.json`. For example:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.3"
}
```

Now PHPUnit will be required for development, but not when the `--no-dev` flag is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but when you deploy a project, you shouldn't be deploying the laravel app with it (/vendor/). You should run composer install and it will pull in all the dependencies. In your composer.json file you can also choose which dependencies are for dev environments only similar to the require-dev section found here: https://gist.github.com/philsturgeon/5976359